# Периодический вызов одной и той же функции через определенные промежутки времени

Tags: java

Есть класс. У него куча методов.
Один из этих методов статический и его надо периодически вызывать в другом месте (например каждые 3 сек).
Подскажите как можно реализовать.

Comment: Используйте `Timer` или запустите метод в отдельном потоке и после каждого вызова (в бесконечном цикле) делайте  `Thread.sleep(3000);`

Comment: @LEQADA Почему не добавить ответ?

Comment: @DanielShatz, потому что не считаю это достойным ответа. Хорошо бы привести пример. Но для того, чтобы привести пример, ТС должен подробнее описать проблему.

Comment: Проблемы нет. Автор вопроса спрашивает варианты  реализации.

Comment: Можно использовать daemon поток с методом sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Можно, к примеру, использовать [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

```
static int seconds = 1;

static void aliveMethod(){ // Ваш статический метод
    System.out.println("I'm alive!");
}

static class AliveTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        aliveMethod(); // Вызываем метод из таймера
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new AliveTask(), 0, seconds*1000); 
}
```

Так же, можно использовать потоки:

```
static int seconds = 1;
static boolean flag = true; // Можете где-нибудь потом сделать false и остановить поток

static void aliveMethod(){ // Ваш статический метод
    System.out.println("I'm alive!");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(flag) {
                    Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                    aliveMethod(); // Вызываем метод из потока
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException v) {
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```